# Vue JS - Check if all items in an array are loaded before firing a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vuex

I have an array prop named trashData and each item in this array is loaded as a custom marker in maps. My issue is that most of the times, the markers are rendered before all the data in 'trashData' is loaded. Therefore if I have 100 items in 'trashData', only a very small number of markers appear, because 'trashData' wouldn't have managed to load all the items in the array before the markers are created. What can I do to have all the items in 'trashData' load before the markers are created? I'm aware that something like setTimeout could be used, however I don't feel as this is very optimal.

TrashData is a prop in this component and it makes a call to the getters in another component. Is it possible to check whether the prop 'trashData' has loaded all the items it needs from the api before firing the relevant function to create the markers?

Trash.vue

```
props: {
    trashData: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  watch: {
    trashData: function (newValue) {
      console.log(newValue);
    }
  },
 methods: {
    createCustomOverlay: function (marker) {
      console.log("markers loaded");
      const imageUrl = this.$props.isReportedTrash ? this.getImageUrl(marker.imageUrl) : this.getImageUrl(marker.imageUrlBefore);
      let overlay = createCustomOverlay({
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        lat: marker.location.lat,
        lng: marker.location.lon,
      });
      overlay.setMap(this.googleMap);
      return overlay;
    },

   createAndAddMarkers: function () {
      this.googleMapMarkers = this.trashData.map(marker => {
        const overlay = this.createCustomOverlay(marker);
        this.addMarkerClickListener(marker, overlay);
        return overlay;
      });
   }
}
```

TrashOverview.vue - this is where 'trashData' is used as 'collectedTrash'.

```
computed: {
    collectedTrash: function () {
      return this.$store.getters.getCollectedTrash;
    }
  },
methods: {
    getCollectedTrash: function (page = -1, sort = TYPES_SORTING.DESC_CREATED_AT) {
      this.$store.dispatch(GET_COLLECTED_TRASH, {page: page, sort: sort});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to check whether the prop 'trashData' has loaded all
> the items it needs from the api before firing the relevant function to
> create the markers?

You can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) : you push all your requests to the API in an array of Promises, and then you wait for it with `Promise.all().`

```
const promiseN = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  getDataFromApi().then((result) => {
    resolve(result);
}});

Promise.all([promise1, ..., promiseN]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```